# How do you learn Balti?

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, online-learning

I am trying to take a trip to Pakistan and I want to learn the local language in preparation. The area I am focused on (Skardu and a few other areas in Gilgit-Baltistan) seems to speak Balti but it's not exactly something I can find on duolingo. To make things worse I really struggle with self-guided unstructured learning so I am not the kind of person who can just pick up a textbook and learn. Do you know how to connect with a teacher who can teach Balti or a course I can take? I am comfortable with online learning. Also my native language is English.

Comment: Contact the University of Baltistan and ask them: https://uobs.edu.pk/index.php

Comment: They are also on facebook: https://www.facebook.com/p/Baltistan-University-Official-100064151890145/

Comment: Sorry for the late response Lambie. I sent an email to the Head of Department Languages and Cultural Studies Dr. Issa and will see if I get a response. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Oh great. I am sure they have some student there or even professor that might give you lessons. Good luck!